# PPPoE doesn't work - cannot reach any website

Tags: networking, pppoe

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my ASUS notebook computer. I can only use the wireless network, but PPPoE doesn't work.

I configured PPPoE using [this Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE) (just using some commands like `pppoeconf` & `poff` & `pon dsl-provider` & so on...)

Everything seemed to go well, but when I try to ping some website I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this problem, which I believe was caused by some conflict between my configuration and `network-manager-gnome`. Once the system finds a connection, network-manager seems to take ownership of it.

For some reason (bugs?) I get an error like this:

```
(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4' failed in libnm-glib.
```

I don't know the exact cause, but I HAVE found a way out.

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

start pppoe manually

```
pon dsl-provider
```

stop pppoe manually

```
poff dsl-provider
```

After that, uninstall network-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Then reboot your computer. Now you can use `pon dsl-provider` to start your DSL connection.

If you want to restore the previous state, just reinstall network-manager using:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager
```